# Problems with init NSItemProvider from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I had app with safari extension. It was using file as a source:

```
NSItemProvider *attachment = [[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"easylist_with_acceptable_ads" withExtension:@"json"]];
  NSExtensionItem *item = [[NSExtensionItem alloc] init];
  item.attachments = @[attachment];
  [context completeRequestReturningItems:@[item] completionHandler:nil];
```

But now i'm going to get it from CoreData and I have NSString with JSON data that is equal to data from file easylist_with_acceptable_ads.json

How can I init NSItemProvider with NSString apart from contents of url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late to the party but:

`NSItemProvider *attachment = [[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithItem:yourJsonString typeIdentifier:@"public.json"];`